# RRDs::fetch implementation using RRDtool

Tags: perl, rrdtool, rrd

I have some legacy code which uses the [RRDs](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/prog/RRDs.en.html) module (RRDs::fetch), but now the RRD file generation is changed.

A 64-bit program is generating an RRD file which can't be read by 32-bit Perl. So I am planning to use the 64-bit RRDtool to imitate the RRDs:: fetch behavior. Is there a sample implementation?

Comment: I believe the binary distributions of rrdtool come with rrdfech http://linux.die.net/man/1/rrdfetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `rrdtool fetch`. On the other hand, you might also want to think about installing a 64-bit Perl and then just use the 64-bit vesion of `RRDs::fetch`.

Note that you could use [App::perlbrew](http://search.cpan.org/~gugod/App-perlbrew-0.24/lib/App/perlbrew.pm) to install Perl in a private directory.

Or if you want to install Perl AND RRDtool without disturbing the rest of your system, have a look at *[Simple Dependency Build Scripts](https://github.com/oetiker/sdbs)*.